# how can i display the first day of the week in rich-faces 4.2

Tags: jsf, calendar, richfaces

how to display an output box that will show the first day of the week.for example, i chose Thursday of that week, i want the output box to display the Monday of that selected week.i am using rich-faces.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with richfaces, apart perhaps from receiving a `Date` from a date selection box. Once you have the Date object (e.g. `yourDate`), you need Java to do the date manipulation:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
Date monday = c.getTime();
System.out.println(yourDate+" --> "+monday);
```

output, e.g.:

```
Fri May 24 00:36:03 CEST 2013 --> Mon May 20 00:36:03 CEST 2013
```